# Display android TextViews like html would floating divs

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I have three TextView elements within a RelativeLayout container:
@+id/name, @+id/message, @+id/time

The @+id/message is positioned by layout to right of @+id/name and @+id/time is to the right of @+id/message. It renders fine as long as the three elements don't take up the width of the screen, but when it does, it bounces up the last element.

I want it to overflow below if this happenens. The best way I can think of it would be having 3 html divs

```
<div style='float:left;'>name</div>
<div style='float:left'>message</div>
<div style='float:left;'>time</div>
```

Comment: please post the relevant layout code

Answer (score 0):

The custom FlowLayout class can be used to display the children in a line and then if there is not enough space start a new line:
https://github.com/triposo/barone/blob/master/src/com/triposo/barone/FlowLayout.java

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could try getting the screen size and then dynamically creating these elements depending on the screen size?